# Sort files in staging area by amount of changed lines

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a Magento 1.9.4 and I upgraded to 1.9.4.3. First I downloaded the full 1.9.4.3 project from Magento. Then I copied over my magento installation.

But I noticed that nearly every file was changed, because magento changed the copyright date. This makes it hard to see the real difference in code logic.

Is there a way to sort the modified files by the amount of changed code lines? This way all of the files where only the copyright was changed will get "sorted out", because these files always have 2 lines changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :  `git diff --stat`

This will list the modified files, along with a number, which indicates the sum of "added + removed lines" detected by the diff algorithm.

---

Here is a quick way to turn this output into a list of files sorted by number of modifications :

```
git diff --stat | awk '{ print $3, $1 }' | sort -rn
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great on shell, I guess it just don't work in sourcetree.